# Updating Xamarin forms app to latest version stops it compiling

Tags: xamarin, build, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2017

I'm fed up to the back teeth with the Visual Studio 2017 Xamarin tools.

I had my application compiling and running in UWP and Android in Debug mode, for Android 8.0. However, when I ran it in Release mode on Android, when I tried to capture a picture from the camera, the app crashed.

I'm using Plugin.Media.Abstractions to control the camera. I read their documentation, and it said I must call `CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, bundle);` before using the package, but there is no such method.

So I looked in package manager, and there were lots of updates (including the Plugin). So I updated.

Then the grief started. I could not update because I was targeting Oreo 8.0. So I updated Visual Studio (many GB of download), restarted, changed the target to 8.1, and updated everything.

Now I can't compile anything! The first error I get is:

```
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is ..\..\packages\NETStandard.Library.2.0.1\build\NETStandard.Library.targets.
```

All the references have a warning triangle against them in solution explorer.

I have closed VS, deleted the .vs folder, the obj and bin folders, reopened it - no change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: update the .net standard nuget reference to 2.0.3

Comment: How? I open NuGet package manager, and it shows no updates. If I looked at all the installed packages, I don't see one called ".net standard".

Comment: unload the csproj and remove the line "..\..\packages\NETStandard.Library.2.0.1\build\NETStandard.Library.targets", reload the csproj and compile it

Comment: does it work now?

Comment: No. I now get thousands of errors like `The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'`.

Comment: ok, now install NETStandard.Library 2.0.3 correctly via NuGet again

Comment: Define "correctly". I went to package manager, found net standard library, checked all projects, uninstalled it, and installed it again. Made no difference.